# EWS Authentication: OAuth with service account

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices

I have below code and working fine when i am running the application from local machine.

But I am getting below exception while running the same application using a service account

```
// Configure the MSAL client to get tokens
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
    .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"]).Build();

// The permission scope required for EWS access
var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/.default" };

//Make the toekn request
AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();


Exception : An error occurred while sending the request. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task
```

Exception in is on
AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Nidheesh

Comment: the most likely cause is a blank or invalid client secret I would suggest you check the value of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"] at runtime to see if its what you expect

Comment: Thank you Glen.. I am getting proper value - then only issue is from service account

Comment: There's no security context being used in your code so it shouldn't matter who it runs as, you need to look more at the response that is coming back. Try using something like fiddler to look at the Request and response being made

Comment: This code is working fine when I am running from local machine. For production I created an exe and exe is running from sql server job. To run the job I created a proxy account using service account. And while running the job am getting that exception. I believe this is something to do with service account. Thank you

Comment: So you have a Proxy Server that you code needs to talk through and that proxy server expect the user to be authenticated? you have nothing in your code to deal with proxies if it works locally then adaptive proxies are probably the reason https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/proxy-configuration. You need to think a little bit more about how this is going to work in your context eg probably it won't be able to get proxy configuration etc given the context its being run in. As a first step maybe test it locally by setting the proxy server config and creds